# Replace 1 line break with 2 line breaks in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

How can I stretch some string element `_text` from

```
A
B
C
```

to

```
A

B

C
```

?

Actually, I have some text getting from DB

```
_text = this.NormalizeString(DinamicLibrary.LoadText(DinamicLibrary.Path[(int)_category] + _textdllName, this.TextNumber));
```

What should I do with this query or with `_text` later to get what I want? 
I understand that I should change `\n` to `\n\n` but dunno how.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470385/how-to-insert-spaces-between-the-characters-of-a-string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var result = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw, is it possible to replace from 3rd match?

Comment: @garm0nboz1a, Do you mean from 3rd `\r\n`?

Comment: Does System.String support the multiply operator? ie (Environment.NewLine * 2) == "\n\n"? Would be cool :)

Comment: @MattDavey, Yo can use: `var result = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(Environment.NewLine, 2)));`

Comment: @garm0nboz1a, For matching from 3rd `\r\n` see my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743660/c-string-manipulations/6743903#6743903

Answer (score 2):

```
string newString = oldString.Replace("\n", "\n\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string newString = oldString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

To match from 3rd `\r\n` you can use regex: `(?s)(?<=(?:\r\n[^\r\n]*){2})\r\n`, e.g.:

```
var s = @"A
B
C
D
E
F";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)(?<=(?:\r\n[^\r\n]*){2})\r\n", Environment.NewLine + 
    Environment.NewLine);
```

Output:

```
A
B
C

D

E

F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate newlines, using `_text.Replace("\n", "\n\n");`. You actually provided that answer, I just knew the name of the method to call :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Environment.NewLine and String.Replace()

```
_text.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

typically a line break is a combination of \r and \n, which equals to Environment.NewLine("\r\n"). But a single \n can also perform a line break. Both are good, just use replace method to add another line breaker.