# How to add a space before and after special characters

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to add a space before and after special characters in a string, but only if that special character is inbetween numbers.
For example:
1/2 should become 1 / 2
1/2/3 should become 1 / 2 / 3
4,6 should become 4 , 6
8a,b would remain 8a,b
8,9a would become 8 , 9a
1,6,a,c would become 1 , 6,a,c
So on and so forth.
I know that you can use the below code to replace special characters with something else, but I'm not sure how to replace that same special character and a space before and after.

```
Regex.Replace(your_String, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "Something Else");
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: It depends. If what you consider special characters is a known list or is it just those 2 characters `,` and `/` ?

Comment: @Franck Hey, so basically non-letters and non-numbers would be considered special characters in my case.

Comment: Expecting large set of text or not your easiest solution remain looping on a buffer (for very large string) or directly on the full array (on smaller strings) and just read character per character and check if their byte value fall within the range for 0-9 a-Z which is just 1 if statement and copy the content in a `StringBuilder` by adding or not spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert spaces between the characters of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470385/how-to-insert-spaces-between-the-characters-of-a-string)

Comment: @Franck Ah - was hoping to avoid that :(.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks - but unfortunately not - I already knew how to insert spaces between all characters - just don't know how to apply the rules in my posting :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so basically non-letters and non-numbers would be considered special
> characters in my case

You could use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1), along with [Char.IsLetterOrDigit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isletterordigit?view=netcore-3.1) and [Char.IsDigit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netcore-3.1), like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "1/2 1/2/3 4,6 8a,b 8,9a 8,9a 1,6,a,c";
    Console.WriteLine("input = " + input);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
    int i = 1;
    while(i < (sb.Length-1))
    {
        // "so basically non-letters and non-numbers would be considered special characters"
        if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(sb[i]))
        {
            // is there a digit to the left and right?
            if (Char.IsDigit(sb[i-1]) && Char.IsDigit(sb[i+1]))
            {
                sb.Insert(i, ' ');
                sb.Insert(i+2, ' ');
                i = i + 3;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }                
    }

    input = sb.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("input = " + input);

    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So typically i would go for a single loop keeping log of what the previous character was and just loop once to have the fastest code while having the easiest time maintaining it.

```
// some test data
var data = "adw/412f,9 356#%7";

// much faster string building class
var sb = new StringBuilder();

// flag for spacing on non special char
var previousIsSpecial = false;

// linq to check each char only once
data.ToList().ForEach(c =>
{
    // get the byte once
    var b = (byte)c;

    // if it's a non special character. Decided to exclude [space], 0-9, a-z, A-Z
    if (b == 32 || (b >= 48 && b <= 57) || (b >= 65 && b <= 90) || (b >= 97 && b <= 122))
    {
        // add a space if the previous char was special and add the current character
        sb.Append((previousIsSpecial ? " " : "") + c);

        // mark this character as "not" special for the next loop
        previousIsSpecial = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // always add the space before a special character
        sb.Append(" " + c);

        // mark this character as special for the next iteration
        previousIsSpecial = true;
    }
});

// get the result
var result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were wanting to use regular expressions, so here is a way to add spaces before and after special characters surrounded by digits using regular expressions. The other loop methods will most likely be more "efficient" like you asked for, but I'm guessing you were maybe meaning efficient as in typing efficiency, and not exactly performance efficiency

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var testValues = new List<string>{@"1/2/3", @"4,6", @"8a,b", @"8,9a", @"1,6,a,c", @"1 2", @"1,,2", @"1234"};
        var digitSpecialDigitPattern = @"(\d)([^0-9a-zA-Z\s])(\d)";
        foreach (var input in testValues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"input: {input}");
            var output = input;
            while (Regex.IsMatch(output, digitSpecialDigitPattern))
            {
                output = Regex.Replace(output, digitSpecialDigitPattern, @"$1 $2 $3");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"output: {output}");
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this program and make changes to it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/pEc6Ok